# Problema al pasar un archivo txt a utf8 mediante bat

Tags: cmd, powershell

tengo un problema al convertir un archivo txt a utf-8, actualmente estoy utilizando este código en powershell para ejecutarlo desde un archivo .bat:

```
powershell -Command "Get-Content .\Myfile.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 Myfile.txt"
```

pero una vez que se ejecuta el archivo se ve de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"E M V L a s t T r a n s a c t i o n"

quiero que al pasar, las letras queden todas juntas.

Comment: Parece que .bat no reconoce el utf-8, y lo interpreta como ASCII.